# Action in TFS after completing pull request

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, pull-request

Is it possible to trigger some action after completing a pull request in TFS ?

Let's say for exemple that a product backlog item is attached as a "related work items" in a pull request.

Could you change it's state automatically after validating the pull request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using TFVC as source control. Work item will be resolved after the check in action. However, it's not support for GIT in TFS now.

You can submit a feature request in uservoice, TFS admin will kindly review it：

> **Uservoice Site:**
>   https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services